# Mongo DB : update some field of document as well push reference in one FindbyIdandUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many, updates

Thank you for helping me, I am new to Mongo DB and I am implementing Many to Many Relationship via Reference.

Note: I know how to do to it in different call's I want to update in one call with best practice

Use Case: **Doctor and Speciality (Many to Many).**

When a doctor is been updating like adding specialty into his profile's also updating it's some of the personal information like Phone, State City.

Required
*It reference array need to be updated along with its fields.
also, the Speciality array needs to be updated by a doctor to speciality Reference array.*

**Doctor Schema**

```
const doctorSchema = new Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
email : {
    type : String,
    required : true,
    unique : true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: value => {
        if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
            throw new Error({error: 'Invalid Email address'})
        }
    }
},
Name : {
    type : String
},
password : {
    type : String,
    required : true,
    minLength : 7
},
gender : {
    type : String
},
address : {
    type : String
},
state : {
    type : String
},
city : {
    type : String
},
zip : {
    type : Number
},
phone : {
    type : Number,
    required : true,
    unique : true
}doctorSpecialities : [{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref  : "Specialty"
}]};
```

**Speciality Schema**

```
const specialtySchema = new Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name :{
    type : String
},
specialtiesDoctors : [{
    type :  Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref  :  'Doctor'
}]
});
```

module.exports = mongoose.model('Specialty', specialtySchema);

**Doctor Update Profile Call**

```
updateDoctorInfo : async (req, res) => {
    /** mongoose _id validation */
    if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)){
        return res.status(400).json({
            "Success" : false,
            "Message" : 'Doctor Id wrong format'
        })
    }
    /** mongoose _id Speciality Validation */
    if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.body.speciality)){
        return res.status(400).json({
            "Success" : false,
            "Message" : 'Speciality Id wrong format'
        })
    }
    /** updating Doctor's Profile */
    let doctor = {};
    doctor.username        = req.body.username,
    doctor.phone            = Date.parse(req.body.DOB),
    doctor.gender          = req.body.gender,
    doctor.address         = req.body.address,
    doctor.state           = req.body.state,
    doctor.city            = req.body.city,
    doctor.zip             = Number(req.body.zip),
    doctor.speciality      = req.body.speciality,
    

    Doctor.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, doctor, {new: true}, function (err, doctor) {
        if (err){
            return res.status(500).send("There was a problem updating the user.");  
        }
        return res.status(200).send(doctor);
    });
},
```

All I wanted to update both reference Array in speciality and Doctor in this call.

Please help i am stuck for almost 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Doctor.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set: req.body,$push: { doctorSpecialities:  req.body.speciality} }, {new: true}, function (err, doctor) {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).send("Error" + err);  
        }else {
            Specialty.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.speciality,{$push: { specialtiesDoctors:  doctor._id}}, {new: true}, function (err, speciality) {
                if(!err){
                    return res.status(200).send({'Success' : true , 'Data' : doctor});
                }
            });
        }
    });
```